# Why is the bloom effect colored?

Tags: artifacts

I've seen many photos where the bloom has a color close to the color of its source.

From what I've read, the bloom is caused by an overflowing of the potential well into neighboring sensors. Since this happens after the color filtering, the bloom should be completely white every time, no?

It's a bit hard to find an example since people avoid taking pictures with bloom, but this looks like what I'm talking about:

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/91/Blooming_ccd.jpg]

Did I understand it wrong, or is it caused by other effects?

EDIT: found some better examples:

[image: Bloom in strobe lights]

[Video of a blue strobe light](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yywck7u5Dto)

Comment: Welcome to Foto.se! Out of curiosity, where was this picture taken?

Comment: Hi and thanks! I don't really, know, it comes from https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/91/Blooming_ccd.jpg, found it in this pdf: http://aeroramon.com/Book_V_Camera_aeroramon.pdf

Comment: Most of the bloom *is* solid white. The sun is actually a small fraction of the size of the white circle.

Comment: Yes, most of the bloom is white, what I don't understand is how the sun's "original" color information is preserved, when the sensors that contained it are saturated.

Comment: What is the sun's original color information?

Comment: [That's a very complex question actually](http://solar-center.stanford.edu/SID/activities/GreenSun.html)! Looks like yellow or orange, from a camera.

Comment: There are different ways for this effects. One is a electronical misinterpretation on the sensor (the long white solid beam horizontal or vertical on the sensor), I don't know how this exactly works, but somebody explained to me that the charge on a singe pixel is that high, that it  affects other pixels in that row in the process of reading out the sensor. 
The other effect maybe is the possibility of  diffraction on the aperture blades in combination with the different refraction angles of the different wavelengths of the light.

Comment: @Horitsu [Please put your answers in the answers section, even if they're short](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4655/please-put-your-answers-in-the-answers-section-even-if-theyre-short)

Comment: The second photo is more like a result of strange saturation settings in the post processing, where similar colors got way different settings and result in not good color transitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have three channels of color information (red, green, blue), and not all of them saturate at exactly the same level, unless the object being (over-)exposed has exactly equal levels of each of the wavelengths that are passed through the mosaic filter in front of the sensor.

Comment: Would you know why they saturate at different levels? Do the potential wells have different capacities?

Comment: @BernardLupiac Each channel has different sensitivity at different wavelengths. The source is not monochromatic.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways for this effects. One is a electronical misinterpretation on the sensor (the long white solid beam horizontal or vertical on the sensor), I don't know how this exactly works, but somebody explained to me that the charge on a singe pixel is that high, that it affects other pixels in that row in the process of reading out the sensor. The other effect maybe is the possibility of diffraction on the aperture blades in combination with the different refraction angles of the different wavelengths of the light.